# PHP: Convert comma separated list into multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a columns string (comma separated list of columns) as such:

```
$columns = "project,description,due_date,tags";
```

Convert into this:

```
$columns = array(
  array( 'db' => 'project',  'dt' => 1 ),
  array( 'db' => 'description',  'dt' => 2 ),
  array( 'db' => 'due_date',  'dt' => 3 ),
  array( 'db' => 'tags',  'dt' => 4 )
);
```

Comment: What did you try so far ?

Comment: `explode(',', $csv_string)` , then create the array to your liking and insert items from array returned by explode.

Comment: @marcolz many different variations with implode and foreach, where it wouldn't help anyone having the same issue if I wrote my tries in the question

Comment: Not to mention [str_getcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) and [array_map](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to format the structure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this**

```
    <?php
    $columns = "project,description,due_date,tags";
    $columns = explode(",", $columns);
    $cArray = array();
    foreach ($columns as $key => $value) {
        $cArray[$key]['db'] = $value;
          $cArray[$key]['dt'] = $key+1; 
    }
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($cArray); echo '</pre>';
```

**Output:-**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [db] => project
            [dt] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [db] => description
            [dt] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [db] => due_date
            [dt] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [db] => tags
            [dt] => 4
        )

)

?>
```

Comment: "_Try this_" (code-only) answers are low-value on Stackoverflow because they do a poor job of educating the OP and future readers.  Please always include some explanation and references with every answer that you post.

Answer (score 1):

```
$columns = "project,description,due_date,tags";

$col_Arr = explode(',',$columns);
$i=1;
$new_arr = [];
foreach($col_Arr as $val){
    $new_arr[] = array('db'=>$val,'dt'=>$i);
    $i++;
}
echo "<pre>"; print_r($new_arr); echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low-value on Stackoverflow because they do a poor job of educating the OP and future readers.  Please always include some explanation and references with every answer that you post.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this :

```
$arr= explode(",", $columns );
$result = [];
for(int i =0; i<arr.length; i++)
  $result[] = ['db' => $arr[i], 'dt' => i+1];
```

Comment: "_do it like this_" (code-only) answers are low-value on Stackoverflow because they do a poor job of educating the OP and future readers.  Please always include some explanation and references with every answer that you post.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
$columns = "project,description,due_date,tags";
$explode_arr = explode(',', $columns);
$arrayval = "";
for($i=0; $i< count($explode_arr); $i++)
{
  $arrayval[$i]['db'] = $explode_arr[$i];
  $arrayval[$i]['dt'] = ($i+1);
}
print_r($arrayval);
exit;
```

Comment: "_try like this_" (code-only) answers are low-value on Stackoverflow because they do a poor job of educating the OP and future readers.  Please always include some explanation and references with every answer that you post.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to convert the string to an array :

```
$columns = "project,description,due_date,tags";
$columns_array = explode(',', $columns);
// then you need to build your multi-dimensional array
$result = array();
foreach ($columns_array as $key => $item) {
    $result[] = array(
        'db' => $item,
        'dt' => $key+1
    );
}
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$columns = "project,description,due_date,tags";
$myArray = explode(',', $columns);
$len=sizeof($myArray);
for($i=0;$i<$len;$i++){
    $newArr[] = array('db'=>$myArray[$i],'dt'=>$i);
}
 echo '<pre>'; print_r($newArr); echo '</pre>';
```

Working [PHP Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/1iab-ms7m)

Comment: Code-only answers are low-value on Stackoverflow because they do a poor job of educating the OP and future readers.  Please always include some explanation and references with every answer that you post.